# Applying for PhD admission at more than one department in the same university

Tags: phd, graduate-school, research-process, graduate-admissions

I was wondering if it is legal, and also advisable to apply for a PhD position at more than one department in the same university. For e.g. I am interested in representation theory and string theory. So would it be possible to apply to the maths and physics department, or there would be inter-departmental clashes leading to my application being disqualified. I guess the rules would be different. SO what are the rules in US and Europe unis resp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have to ask each university.**

I don't believe there are any *ethical* issues with applying to more than one program.  Moreover, I think it's rare for graduate admissions committees in different departments to share information about applicants.  (In the US, that sharing *might* even run afoul of [FERPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act), but interpretations of FERPA vary wildly from one university to the next.)

However, at some universities, it is not *possible* to apply to more than one department.  At my university, for example, all graduate applications go through a central web site that forces each applicant to choose *exactly one* program.  Yes, I think this is stupid.

Comment: There's no way around that? Even by using slightly different name variations or email accounts?