# Applying for Phd at two different departments, in the same university, but very relevant fields. Would it harm my admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, physics, biology

Biophysics and Condensed matter physics interests me. I am more inclined towards biophysics. 
Would it weaken my application if i applied to both the biophysics program (Biological sciences department) and the condensed matter program (Physics department) in the same university? I want to apply for Condensed matter, in case i didn't get accepted in biophysics, i might get accepted in condensed matter.

P.S. I have a Bachelor's degree in theoretical physics.

Comment: I know a question similar to this was asked before, but i guess my case is different. I believe that biophysics and condensed matter physics are very related to each other.[link](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/applying-for-phd-admission-at-more-than-one-department-in-the-same-university)

Comment: Depending on the university, it wouldn't matter what you applied to, because a bachelor's degree is not sufficient for entry to a doctorate programme. Please add sufficient detail to the question to make it answerable.

Comment: @Nij - What country are you talking about?

Comment: @MohamedAyman - I would frankly be surprised if anyone would even notice you had put in an application to another department in the same university.

Comment: @aparente001 my own. I do not wish to make this explicit.

Comment: @Nij - Sorry, I didn't mean to pry.  At any rate, "a bachelor's degree is not sufficient for entry to a doctorate programme" does not hold true in the U.S.

Comment: @aparente001 not a problem. As per original comment, the question is not detailed enough to make the assumption of a location, hence the need for that particular aspect of the asker's situation to be made clearer.

Comment: @Nij I am sorry, i should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would see no harm in doing so. I view it as akin to applying to different schools when you first start college. To gain a better understanding, I would contact the graduate office at your school about multiple applications to different departments. Policies do vary from campus to campus.